# Unity - Saving an image from a WebGL app to the users machine

Tags: unity-game-engine, screen-capture, data-uri, unity-webgl

I`m building a character creator webGL app and want to enable people to "save" their avatar as a 500x500 PNG file on their desktop.
So far I have been using the exact code from the following source, which works for the Unity Editor:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/48hreq/saving_an_image_from_a_webgl_application_to_the/

However, in that topic they never got around to providing a solid answer on how to prompt the user to either download the generated image, or to open the image in a new tab so that they may download it themselves.

I have been testing multiple scripts, but at the end of the day i havent been able to come closer to a solution by myself.

Any pointers, tips or advice would be greatly helpful!

Comment: Maybe your server could generate the image, set a temporary URL that you can open on the client with Application.OpenURL() ? What server are you using ?

Comment: @Jichael I am currently running tests on an Xampp apache server. I have little experience with intergrating jslib commands with my applications, which seems to be the way to go in these cases.
Also, I was hoping for a client side solution if possible.